# How to configure /clock topic in launch file - costmap_2d

Tags: ros, roslaunch, topic, rosrun, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have this case, when I use `rosrun costmap_2d costmap_2d_node` everything works fine and I get my costmap. But I tried to run this node from a launch file, but this warning appears in the log:

```
[ WARN] [1378418356.560509543]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1378418356.5604, global_pose stamp: 1.6400, tolerance: 0.3000
[ WARN] [1378418356.622218511]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
```

So I supposed was something related with /clock topic. Comparing `rosnode info /costmap_2d` of both executions, the only difference is this connection when using `rosrun`:

```
Connections:
 [...]
 * topic: /clock
    * to: /vinter_sim (http://gustavo-HPprobook:36184/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

What should I do to correctly run this node from .launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76792/how-to-configure-/clock-topic-in-launch-file---costmap_2d/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-09-08**:
Thanks, I add this line `param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/` and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @felix_k said, I add this line to may launch file and it works:

```
<param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
```

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you set `use_sim_time` somewhere within that launch file or within any included launch file?

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1